# How can I cancel a StreamSubscription that I open in my main function

Tags: flutter, dart

I am not sure if I am following the right approach here. I want to listen to connectivity changes using the connectivity package (https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity#-readme-tab-).

But I don't want to listen to connectivity changes on a specific screen/widget. Instead I want the app to listen to connectivity changes globally, and synchronize data when the connection comes back online.

My first approach was to put

```
var StreamSubscription subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
// Got a new connectivity status! })
```

in my main function. But then I get an error that reminds me that I need to cancel opened subscriptions. How would I do that if I open the streamsubscription in my main function?
Or should I put the subscription listener somewhere else?

Thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **main** function has a call to **runApp** that displays the top class of your app.
When creating a new flutter app - it's called **MyApp**. I'll use it as an example.

What you can do, is change the **MyApp** to become a **StatefulWidget**. After this you can use it's **initState** to create a subscription, that will live until the app is closed.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // Define a class variable to hold your subscription
  StreamSubscription subscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // initialize subscription
    subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
      print('Got a new connectivity status!');
      print(result.toString());
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // cancel your subscription when the class is removed
    subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      .....
    );
  }
}
```

*PS.* Don't forget to always cancel any subscription on class dispose.

Hope this helps.

Comment: will that work across all state changes, e.g. when the app is frozen and resumed?

Comment: It will trigger even if the app is in the background mode. You can just paste the code above, run it, press the "home" button and enable/disable the wifi connection. The app will still output connection changes to the console.